# user-defined operators in C++

Tags: c++, operators

What do you think about an imaginary possibility to specify user-defined operators in C++.

Such user-defined operator could be defined by operator name (arbitrary sequence of allowed chars?), its precedence, associativity and arity (something else?).

They could be used for many purposes: to help to build "tiny" DSLs over C++, for list comprehension etc.

Wouldn't this feature extend the language possible usage? What are other languages that allow user-defined operators? Lisp comes to mind, anything else? Any links about the topic?

Comment: I'm sure the C++ standard committee has already discussed many variations on this idea and felt it wasn't worthwhile.  For one thing, C++ is hard enough to parse as it is.  For another, what would the precedence and associativity of new operators be?  Function-call syntax lets you define whatever names you want and there's no ambiguity concerning grouping.

Comment: Consider transfer this question to wiki

Comment: By DNS (?), do you mean DSL (Domain Specific Language)?

Comment: @Ben: Good comment, should be an answer.

Comment: @Artem: flagged it, @Macke: sure :) tnx

Comment: @Andy, consider refining a bit? This is an _extremely_ subjective and open ended question. Making it CW doesn't solve that.

Comment: @Macke: Nah, an answer to a question like this requires more sarcasm, just to combat the self-importance expressed by the poster.

Comment: @Time: any suggestions? btw I don't understand why it's subjective, just asked what community thinks about this. yeah, it's open-ended, it's why I flagged this as community wiki for moderators

Comment: @Ben: can you pls elaborate what is self-important? I'll try to edit the question. I hope it was just a problem of my imperfect English

Comment: @Andy: Your tone in writing the question comes across as very presumptuous because there's an attitude that you thought of something brand new and are therefore smarter than all the people who designed C++.  As you can see from BS April Fools Joke ([linked by Chris](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130504/user-defined-operators-in-c/5130580#5130580)), this is not a new idea.  So "Why did the designers choose not to allow this?" in a better question than "Wouldn't this be great?"

Comment: @Andy: And yes it is possible for a English-as-a-second-language speaker to phrase a question like that purely by accident, so most native speakers try not to take offense but use a little sarcasm to let you know what you've done and hope you learn from it.

Comment: @Ben: "Why did the designers choose not to allow this?" formulation would be appropriate for a perfect language. Also I haven't used quite opposite and naive "Wouldn't this be great?".

Comment: @Andy: For a perfect language, or for a feature which was already considered and excluded.  It's usually safe to assume that a group of a couple dozen of the world's experts on language design have thought of something before you.  If you ask "why did they choose not to", you look smart, because if you thought of something they didn't, you look smart, and if they did decide not do, you asked a good and reasonable question.  But if you ask "Wouldn't this new idea make the language better?", and it's not such a new idea after all, it makes you look foolish.

Comment: C++ is an open standard and we are all the designers and I think this is a great idea. I see no argument against that is not also against overloading existing operators, but I think it's even safer and smarter. If I overload && (legal) the evaluation order changes. If I write F1() AND F2() there is no expectation of preserving order. I think I'll write a proposal. I found this question because I was looking for a draft proposal and found none.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org) has custom operators with settable precedence and left-right binding. So, it can work.  But then, Haskell is cutting edge and barely readable as is, even though it's mostly used by some rather clever people. (Haskell scares off all newbies, I think..)

For C++, I think there are:

- parsing issues (consider the `std::vector<std::list<int>>` bug, where `>>` was parsed as the right-shift operator) .. C++'s syntax is hard enough as is.
- backwards-compability issues (introducing new operators that are combinations of old, like !-- could cause problems)
- clarity issues (people are doing enough wierd thing with the regular operators, making the behaviour of a program difficult enough to divine as is.)

The latter one is the dealbreaker, IMO.

Nevertheless, nothing is stopping you from writing a c++-preprocessor/parser that replaces your own-defined operators with real function calls and then uses the normal c++ compiler (like how c++ was built on C previously). Would be a neat experiment, if you'd keep your sanity long enough to ship. ;-)

Comment: tnx for good answer. I don't see how this can be achieved as a custom preprocessor. Operators are bound to types, so first you need to parse source. Also such operators would be defined by C++ itself, as operator overloading is done.

Comment: @Andy: Preprocessor might not be the best word. Consider it a compiler that reads "C+++" and emits legal C++. Mainly, it'd just parse the custom operators and translate them into function calls (i.e. a user defined `^_^` operator might be translated `xxx__bracket_underscore_bracket__operator()`, or just `happy_kitty_op()` ;)), with the appropriate chaining depending on arity and left/right binding. It's  a huge undertaking, but I mainly wanted to point out that code transformations like these are not impossible.

Comment: C++ was once a preprocessor of sorts (called cfront) to C.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you know, Bjarne Stroustrup did propose such a thing...[Generalizing Overloading for C++2000](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/whitespace98.pdf). :-P :-P :-P

Comment: @Macke: No, it's not more suitable as a comment. It's an answer, albeit a facetious one. I don't think it's necessary to relegate all "funnies" to comments, or CW, or what have you.

Comment: It is, however, important to note: "The focus is on general ideas rather than technical
details (which can be found in AT&T Labs Technical Report no. 42, April 1,1998)"

Comment: @Ben: The whole paper itself is an April Fool's joke. :-D

Comment: @Chris: I was trying to point that out without making it too obvious. I once gave this paper to a particularly gullible co-worker, he thought it was a VERY GOOD IDEA and was ready to arrange training for the entire development group until he got to the final paragraph.

Comment: @Chris: Well. Ok. But I my vote is locked so I can't un-downvote unless you edit the answer. I also found the paper to be more about whitespace operators rather than user-defined ops, hence my downvote. (And I suppose I was overly cranky at the time... sorry)

Comment: Dead link, but you can find the original PDF in the wayback machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20060222013825/http://public.research.att.com/~bs/whitespace98.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I fail to understand the advantage of such operators. Functions and methods are sufficient for every kind of use I can think of.

I think such a possibility would only make C++ a lot more complex and reduce readability of sources. Operators overriding is already such a mess in some sources that I can't imagine what some people would do with operators definition...

BTW, I really don't understand what you mean by "tiny DNSs over C++"

Comment: Do you consider that there is only one type of multiplication between matrices or that one of them is less worthy of inflix notation than the other ?

Comment: @Krtek: I think the OP meant DSL, not DNS. ;-)

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox I consider that every operator overloading reduces the readability of the code. For example if you see myMatrixA * myMatrixB, how do you know which kind of multiplication your performing ? By using only methods call, your code is much more clear. So, none of them are worthy of an infix notation ;)

Comment: @Krtek : I hope for you that you never work on any math-heavy code. Not being able to read, check and think about formulas in code due to language designers decisions is painful. And it's the reason for witch matlab is so successful even while it could be painful to interop with and except for the syntax most of it's feature are available as c/c++ libs.

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox: Matlab doesn't allow defining new operators, it doesn't even allow overloading operators.  However every operator is defined by calling a virtual function, which adequately provides for customizing the behavior.

Comment: @Ben Voigt : Exact i wasn't praising matlab for it's general language design, just citing it as a sample of a language where math oriented operators are available.

Answer (score 1):

So let's say you define ** to mean "to the power of" as a user-operator.

Now you have some code like this:

```
double d1 = 2.5;
double *pd1 = &d1;
double d2 = 3.0**pd1;
```

Without the "operator **" the code above is actually legal, it is parsed as `3.0 * (*pd1)` (and the result is 7.5)

Is the compiler going to know whether the ** is as above or trying to do a "power" (and complain that the right hand side is a pointer).

Having said that I do think `&&=` and `||=` and even `^^` and `^^=` should be added as operators. (I don't think ^^ is logical xor, giving a true if exactly one of the expressions is non-zero).

Answer (score 0):

You may be mixing concepts - user defined operator overloads are ok. This is because the compiler already knows the syntax rules for C++ defined operators.

User defined operators "per se" - no.  Imagine being able to make the word "Klingon" an operator - how will it differentiate between operator and variable?

Comment: I think the OP is well aware of operators overloading. People talking about associativity and arity usually knows what they are talking about ;) Differentiation between operators and variable will be made with the context, nothing too difficult here, at least for the compiler.